# How to create a sitemap that includes links of the navigation menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-crawler, sitemap

I have a website in which there is a navigation menu in each HTML page. In order to implement this, there is a JavaScript function that is called and writes the navigation panel with all the links

```
<!------------------------------------------------------------------------
                      HEADER Navigation bar  
------------------------------------------------------------------------>
<script>
   insertHeader();
</script>
```

Thus, if there is a change, it is done only in the JavaScript file and is automatically applied to dozens of pages across the website.

**Problem**:
I am trying to generate a sitemap with [this tool](https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/). However, since my navigation panel is not written in the HTML (but inserted by JS), this tool does not recognize the navigation. As a result 99.9% of my website is not recognized. Other tools I saw also behave similar behavior.

1) How can I overcome this problem?

2) Will google crawlers see the other links I have in navigation panel?

Comment: How is the information structured in the JS function? Is it reading a JSON file?

Comment: It has just a "document.write(...here I write the HTML code...)" function.

Comment: If you could, it would be helpful to separate the data from the code, and have the menu information in a separate file (in JSON, XML, or any format that you want). Then you could read that file from JS and generate the menus, and read the file from the back-end and generate the sitemap.

Comment: Thank you, but I am not sure I understood what you meant (p.s. I am also not familiar with JSON). could you give an exmaple of what should I do?

Comment: It is tough to explain in a comment, but here it goes: if you have the data in JSON (e.g.: `[ { "name":"option1", "url":"http://myurl.com" }, ... ]`), you could read it from JavaScript; but instead of just having a big `document.write`, you'd have a loop with small `document.write`s (e.g.: `document.write("<li><a href='" + data.url + "'>" + data.name + "</a></li>")`) to generate the menu. Then you could also read the JSON file using a scripting language (e.g.: PHP, Ruby, Python...) and generate the sitemap without any other tools.

Comment: As a side comment, having the menu the way you described is a nightmare in the long run: it is difficult to maintain, prone to errors, difficult to parse and/or reuse (your case with the sitemap), fails if the user doesn't have JS activated in the browser... I would recommend changing it to a database or at least to a more readable/reusable format (XML/JSON). But that's my opinion :)

Answer (score 0):

This question is very old, but I ran into the same problem as you. I also create my nav using JavaScript. To be able to generate my sitemap, what I did was copy the JavaScript generated nav into my index.html temporarily. Then after successfully running the sitemap generator, the copied nav can be removed from index.html.